# Installing Vodafone k4203 modem on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: usb, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

When i plug my usb modem device, it's mounted as mass storage and i can see the setup folder. But i have problem when install the driver..

This is QuickStartInstallation.txt i found in usb modem

> Welcome to Vodafone QuickStart.
>
> This provides a simple and easy way for customers to get access to the
> internet via Vodafone Mobile Broadband. Please follow these
> instructions to setup your QuickStart device.  As all Linux systems
> are slightly different so it is impossible to give a definitive set of
> instructions, but these are the typical installation procedure steps
> for 32bit Ubuntu 11.10.
>
> 1. Insert stick
> 2. Dismiss all popups about running the auto install scripts
> 3. Open terminal
> 4. cd $HOME
> 5. mkdir vfinstall
> 6. cd vfinstall
> 7. (cd /media/"Vodafone Mobile Broadband" && tar -cvf - .) | tar -xf
> 8. chmod +x autorun.sh install_linux
> 9. sudo ./autorun.sh
> 10. Type user password
> 11. Wait for last command to finish, then close terminal

I follow the instruction and have problem at step 7.

> (cd /media/jonathan/"Vodafone Mobile Broadband" && tar -cvf - .) | tar -xf
>
> tar: \302\226: Cannot open: No such file or directory tar: Error is
> not recoverable: exiting now ./ ./ArConfig.dat ./autorun.inf
> ./autorun.sh ./Data/ ./Data/ISSetupPrerequisites/
> ./Data/ISSetupPrerequisites/{24AE63B7-81E1-4216-8226-964B1AE12701}/
> ./Data/ISSetupPrerequisites/{24AE63B7-81E1-4216-8226-964B1AE12701}/Generic/
> ./Data/ISSetupPrerequisites/{24AE63B7-81E1-4216-8226-964B1AE12701}/Generic/kb909394/
> ./Data/ISSetupPrerequisites/{24AE63B7-81E1-4216-8226-964B1AE12701}/Generic/kb909394/Kb909394.exe

I try to move the next step and sure, it's giving me an error to. Thanks

Comment: Please run `cd /media/jonathan` then `ls -l` and paste into your question

Comment: Also add `ls -l /media` to your question